# Bootstrap 2-column tabs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a nav-tabs ul render its contents in 2 columns and not horizontally (which is the default style for bootstrap nav-tabs).

I tried the css property `column-count: 2` but it doesn't work

Below is my code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs ml-0 mr-0 bg-primary two-columns" role="tablist" style="column-count: 2;">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#cont1"  role="tab">Title 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link       " data-toggle="tab" href="#cont2"  role="tab">Title 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link       " data-toggle="tab" href="#cont3"  role="tab">Title 3</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link       " data-toggle="tab" href="#cont4"  role="tab">Title 4</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link       " data-toggle="tab" href="#cont5"  role="tab">Title 5</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link       " data-toggle="tab" href="#cont6"  role="tab">Title 6</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link       " data-toggle="tab" href="#cont7"  role="tab">Title 7</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link       " data-toggle="tab" href="#cont8"  role="tab">Title 8</a></li>
</ul>


<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content ml-2 mr-2">
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron active" id="cont1" role="tabpanel">Conctent 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron active" id="cont2" role="tabpanel">Conctent 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron active" id="cont3" role="tabpanel">Conctent 3</div>
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron active" id="cont4" role="tabpanel">Conctent 4</div>
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron active" id="cont5" role="tabpanel">Conctent 5</div>
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron active" id="cont6" role="tabpanel">Conctent 6</div>
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron active" id="cont7" role="tabpanel">Conctent 7</div>
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron active" id="cont8" role="tabpanel">Conctent 8</div>
</div>
```

and my custom css class `two-columns`

```
ul.two-columns {
    -moz-column-count: 2 !important;
    -moz-column-gap: 2.5em !important;
    -webkit-column-count: 2 !important;
    -webkit-column-gap: 2.5em !important;
    column-count: 2 !important;
    column-gap: 2.5em !important;
}
```

I suppose that the JavaScript included in Bootstrap blocks my custom styles.
Below is my code

Has anyone any good idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: do you want vertical nav-tabs

Comment: Practically yes! I want 2 columns vertically stacked. I tried using a table where i added a tab item in each cell. the style was fine, but every item i click, the previous stays in the active state.

Answer (score 0):

try this answer

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.tabs-left{
  border-bottom: none;
  padding-top: 2px;
}
.tabs-left {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.tabs-left>li {
  float: none;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.tabs-left>li {
  margin-right: -1px;
}
.tabs-left>li.active>a,
.tabs-left>li.active>a:hover,
.tabs-left>li.active>a:focus {
  border-bottom-color: #ddd;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.tabs-left>li>a {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  margin-right: 0;
  display:block;
}
</style>

<div class="row" style="min-height:300px;">
    <div  class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <!-- required for floating -->
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left">
               <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#cont1"  role="tab">Title 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#cont2"  role="tab">Title 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#cont3"  role="tab">Title 3</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#cont4"  role="tab">Title 4</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#cont5"  role="tab">Title 5</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#cont6"  role="tab">Title 6</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#cont7"  role="tab">Title 7</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#cont8"  role="tab">Title 8</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <!-- Tab panes -->
           <div class="tab-content ml-2 mr-2">
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron active" id="cont1" role="tabpanel">Conctent 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron" id="cont2" role="tabpanel">Conctent 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron" id="cont3" role="tabpanel">Conctent 3</div>
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron" id="cont4" role="tabpanel">Conctent 4</div>
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron" id="cont5" role="tabpanel">Conctent 5</div>
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron" id="cont6" role="tabpanel">Conctent 6</div>
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron" id="cont7" role="tabpanel">Conctent 7</div>
    <div class="tab-pane jumbotron" id="cont8" role="tabpanel">Conctent 8</div>
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li  class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
   <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home"  class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```